# Android MediaPlayer: wrong seek after start playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've got a strange situation that I can't understand. I set a seek for MediaPlayer, call .play() and the seek is in 10 secs in future. Code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "start: seek before start " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
mediaPlayer.start();
Log.d(TAG, "start: current seek right after start " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
try { Thread.sleep(50); 
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
Log.d(TAG, "start: current seek after 50 ms after start is " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

And in the log we have the next:

```
D/PlayerActivity﹕ start: seek before start 449586
D/PlayerActivity﹕ start: current seek right after start 0
D/PlayerActivity﹕ start: current seek after 50 ms after start is 457883
```

I can't understand why it's moved forward on 10 seconds?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the root cause is a bad metainf in the mp3 file. There is nothing to do with the MediaPlayer...